# What are errorIndication, errorStatus and errorIndex providing in PySNMP's nextCmd()?

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I would like to create proper error handling for the PySNMP function nextCmd() and am curious what the parameters errorIndication, errorStatus, and errorIndex are providing as I iterate through nextCmd().

I can not find anything within the documentation regarding these variables and would like to know more.

Comment: Because the actual documentation of such is SNMP standard, http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion2SNMPv2MessageFormats-5.htm

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `errorIndication` as locally occurred errors. Misconfiguration or timeout will be reported via it.

The `errorStatus` and `errorIndex` pair can only come from the remote SNMP entity - that's the way how SNMP peers communicate their failures to us. Any non-zero `errorStatus` means an (enumerated) error. The accompanying `errorIndex` point to the first variable-binding in the request which might have caused the processing error being reported.